# is it possible to specify the pdf viewer in latexmk build command

Tags: latexmk

I am using this command in mac bok pro to build the latex document:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk -pdfxe -pvc -xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory="./output"
```

is it possible to set the pdf viewer in command line like:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk -pdfxe -pvc -xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory="./output" -pdfviewer skim
```

I have searching from google but did not found the clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `-e '$pdf_previewer=q[skim %S];'` to the command line. That will set the `$pdf_previewer` configuration variable to the desired value. See the latexmk documentation for details on the configuration variables.

(The `qq[ ...]` is a Perl idiom equivalent to single quotes surrounding a string, to save running into quote-hell on the command line. The `%S` tells latexmk to substitute the name of the pdf file.)

If your normal viewer is skim, then the best thing is to add the following line

```
$pdf_previewer = 'skim %S';
```

to an appropriate latexmkrc file.  (Again see the latexmk documentation for where to put it.)  Then you won't have to put anything about the viewer on the command line.